# Errorjava sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (1 >)

Tags: java, mysql

i have an error with my Code, but i don't know what is... 
(Java + MySQL)

```
public void deleteClientes(int nit){
   sql = "DELETE FROM `clientes` WHERE `clientes`.`nit` =  ";
   delete(sql,nit);
```

}

Method that receives:

```
 public void delete(String sql,int id){
    final QueryRunner qr = new QueryRunner(true); 
    try {
        qr.update(conexion(),sql,"%"+id+"%");
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
       System.err.println("Error"+ex);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query doesn't have a placeholder `?`. It should be:

```
"DELETE FROM `clientes` WHERE `clientes`.`nit` =  ?"
```

Comment: Nothing, the error don't come out now but not delete the row :(

Answer (score 0):

Need to add `?` into sql statement where data will be placed based on parameter

```
sql = "DELETE FROM `clientes` WHERE `clientes`.`nit` =  ?";
```

and

```
 qr.update(conexion(),sql,id);
```

Comment: Nothing, the error don't come out now but not delete the row :(

Comment: check data type and where condition, data will be deleted if condition matched

Comment: `"%"+id+"%"`, why did you add `%`?

Comment: Listo! the error is fixed...i changed the fragment:  qr.update(conexion(),sql,"%"+id+"%");  by:  qr.update(conexion(),sql,id); and that's it!